# Visual studio Image folder in sub project

Tags: visual-studio

In one of my visual studio projects there are some sub directories each of them containing sub projects. In one such sub-project I have an Image folder containing an image. Now I am not being able to load that image doing something like this.

```
 <img id="loading" src="~/Image/loader.gif" alt="loader">
```

When I hover on it in my dev tool it shows me the path like

```
http://localhost:62360/Image/loader
```

and the image is not found on that location. Any idea what can be done?

Comment: I highly recommend, if its a part of your project like a banner or something, to work with a resource file. It will make the access way more easy that searching between folder and projects. Also, the location can't be changed, like when the folder structure changes. If you are interested I can write you a small instruction with some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

**For everyone with problems like that**

I highly recommend, if its a part of your project that shouldn't be replaced or be replaced, to use a resource file. Here is a small [instrction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246.aspx) how to do so.

You can now simply choose "~/resource/WhatIsThis.png" as URL (usually in the GUI the url can be choosen via dialog).

As said in documentation, it is important to know that the resource file will store the URL to your image, not the image itself. But that won't make a difference in this case.